# a question on elementary extension of full theory of a model

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

> David Marker's Model Theory:
>   If not $Th_{A}(M) \models\phi( \overline{v} )  \rightarrow  \psi( \overline{v} )$, then there is an elementary extension $N$ of $M$ and $\overline{a} \in N$ such that $ N \models \phi( \overline{a} )   \wedge   \neg \psi( \overline{a} )$.

Could you explain why there exists such an elementary extension?
Would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Is $Th_{A}(M) = \{ \phi \in \mathcal L^M_A \mid M_A \models \phi \}$, where $\mathcal L^M_A$ is the language of $M$ together with a constant symbol $c_a$ for each $a \in A \subseteq M$ and the interpretation $c_a^{M_A} = a$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What is $A$?${}{}$

Comment: @Stefan $A$ is a subset of $M$ (as per Stefan's comment above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you meant is if $Th_A(\mathcal{M}) \not \models \phi(\bar{v}) \rightarrow \psi(\bar{v})$, then there is an elementary extension $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ with $\bar{a} \in N$ such that $\mathcal{N} \models \phi(\bar{a}) \wedge \lnot \psi(\bar{a})$.

The point is that if $Th_A(\mathcal{M}) \not \models \phi(\bar{v}) \rightarrow \psi(\bar{v})$, then, by the completeness theorem, there is a model $\mathcal{N}_0 \models Th_A(\mathcal{M})$ such that $\mathcal{N}_0 \models \exists \bar{v} \phi(\bar{v}) \wedge \lnot \psi(\bar{v})$, and hence $Th_A(\mathcal{M}) \cup \{ \phi(\bar{v}), \lnot \psi(\bar{v}) \}$ is satisfiable. By proposition 4.1.3 in that same section, there is an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$ where the type $\{ \phi(\bar{v}), \lnot \psi(\bar{v}) \}$ is realized.

Comment: This is closer, but I still don't think this is what the exercise means to say: if $Th_A(\mathcal{M})\not\models\varphi(v)\rightarrow\psi(v)$, then by definition $\mathcal{M}$ *already* contains $a$ such that $\varphi(a)\wedge\neg\psi(a)$ holds. So there's no need to pass to an elementary extension at all.

Comment: Your answer was excellent Athar! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is false as written: suppose $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are the same formula! Are you sure you've copied it correctly?

Comment: I forgot to write the "not" in the beginning. Sorry about that. Now it's right.